# Load resources recursively with javascripts tag

Tags: symfony

I have a library that has `*.js` files accross a lot of subdirectories.

I'm trying to load the library in my twig like this:

```
{% javascripts
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/library/base.js'
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/library/src/*'
%}
```

But when I run `app:console assetic:dump`, Symfony only dumps the `*.js` files that are located on the root directory `src/`, and ignores all the subdirectories.

Is there any solution for that? Maybe load files recursively?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there is no way to tell assetic to go in any-deep folders.

However, you can still go one directory deeper by using

```
{% javascripts
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/library/src/*'
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/library/src/*/*'
%}
```